# How do I combine two LEFT JOINS without getting crossover?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got two queries I'd like to combine into one, but keep get a matrix effect when I do.

`SELECT u.*, COUNT(q.id)
 FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN questions q ON u.id = q.author_id
 GROUP BY u.id`

`SELECT u.*, COUNT(a.id)
 FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN answers a ON u.id = a.author_id
 GROUP BY u.id`

Those queries by themselves give me a count of 10 for questions and 10 for answers.
When I combine them like below, the question and answer count jumps to 100 each.

`SELECT u.*, COUNT(q.id), COUNT(a.id)
 FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN questions q ON u.id = q.author_id
 LEFT JOIN answers a ON u.id = a.author_id
 GROUP BY u.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add distinct to the counts

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(DISTINCT q.id), COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
 FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN questions q ON u.id = q.author_id
 LEFT JOIN answers a ON u.id = a.author_id
 GROUP BY u.id
```

[Here's a demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173840/question-and-answer-count) of it in action using Data.SE

Alternatively you can use inline views in the from clause

```
SELECT u.*, q.QuestionCount, a.AnswerCount
FROM   users u 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(id) QuestionCount, 
                         author_id 
                  FROM   questions 
                  GROUP  BY author_id) q 
              ON u.id = q.author_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(id) AnswerCount, 
                         author_id 
                  FROM   answers 
                  GROUP  BY author_id) a 
              ON u.id = q.author_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/771be/9)

Comment: With many questions/answers, this becomes inefficient because the database computes all question × answer combinations before applying the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the joins with correlated subqueries that are independent from each other:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions WHERE author_id = u.id),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers   WHERE author_id = u.id)
FROM users u
```